# Flutter+Firebase error upgrading anonymous user to GoogleSignIn (Given String is empty or null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have an anonymous account in Flutter and am trying to upgrade it using an AuthCredential from Google. I have verified the credential is created with what appears to be a valid accessToken and idToken.

So if `auth.currentUser()` is my anonymous FirebaseUser, calling `linkAccountToGoogle()` below causes the error.

```
/// Upgrade an anonymous account by linking it to a Google account.
Future<FirebaseUser> linkAccountToGoogle() async {
  final credential = await _getGoogleAuthCredential();
  if (credential != null) {
    try {
      return auth.linkWithCredential(credential);  // <=== THROWS ERROR
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
  return null;
}

/// Tries to sign-in silently first. May return `null`.
Future<AuthCredential> _getGoogleAuthCredential() async {
  GoogleSignInAccount account;
  try {
    account = await _googleAuthService.signInSilently() ??
        await _googleAuthService.signIn();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  final googleAuth = await account?.authentication;
  if (account == null) {
    print('Unable to retrieve Google account.');
  } else if (googleAuth == null) {
    print('Unable to authenticate to Google account (${account.email}).');
  } else {
    // print(
    //     'accessToken: ${googleAuth.accessToken}, idToken: ${googleAuth.idToken}');
    return GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Stacktrace

```
I/flutter ( 3038): Credential: Instance of 'AuthCredential'
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source:5)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source:2)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.handleLinkWithEmailAndPassword(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:272)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:122)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:200)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView$PlatformMessageHandlerImpl.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterNativeView.java:188)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:202)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 3038):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
E/flutter ( 3038): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Given String is empty or null, null)
E/flutter ( 3038): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
E/flutter ( 3038): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:302:33)
E/flutter ( 3038): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3038): #2      FirebaseAuth.linkWithCredential (file:///home/jacob/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.0+1/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart:371:54)
```

**What I've tried**

The Google account I am trying to link to was already a user for the project, so I deleted that google user from the Firebase console. Then tried again using `flutter clean` `flutter run`.

Comment: It seems like there are a lot of errors surrounding the recent updates (maybe partially AndroidX upgrade related). I had some of these issues as well, but decided to downgrade. Here is a post talking about that more https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27156

Comment: @Jacob Did you find a solution or workaround? I need this too in my project

Comment: No actually, not yet. I downgraded `google_sign_in` to ^3.0.0 but that didn't work. Maybe if I downgrade other AndroidX packages too, I haven't spent much more time on it.

Comment: No recent updated ??

Comment: @ShadyBoshra yes apparently it was fixed in [firebase_auth 0.11.0](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#0110)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Sign-in flow must be triggered first before linking the auth credential of the account to be linked. Base from the errors given, it's likely that the data inside Google Sign-in's AuthCredential is missing something, that's why it throws `Given String is empty or null`

I've tried the code below using `firebase_auth: ^3.3.4` and it works well on my end without issues.

```dart
// Trigger Google Auth flow.
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

// Obtain auth details from the request.
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

// Create a new credential.
final GoogleAuthCredential googleCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);

// Get current anonymous user.
User anonymousUser = auth.currentUser();

// Link anonymous account with Google account.
await anonymousUser.linkWithCredential(googleCredential);
```

Comment: there is an issue that the Firebase authStateChanges won't be called because you are going from signed in to signed In with google (meaning no state change occured). is there any way to fix this?